# Increase max products view per page on 'Manage Products' menu

Tags: products

On Catalog -> Manage Products (Magento 1.8.1)

I want to see 300 or 400 products per a page but magento allow only 200 products per a page

[image]

How can I make I can select more options for number of products per a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a very ugly limitation of magento.
The paging options are hardcoded in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml`.

```
        <select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
            <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
            <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
            <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
            <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
            <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
        </select>
```

To change these values you need to create a new theme for admin and clone the file mentioned above and add your new paging values.
[See here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) how you can change the admin theme.
The good thing is that there is no verification for the paging options you send. So you can add any number in here and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your “/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php”

Look for the line:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Once you find it, paste the below code on the line beneath it:

```
$this->setDefaultLimit(200);
```

Comment: I would highly discourage editing core files. If you really have to, copy the file from the core codepool to the local codepool and edit it there.